# MP3 Player on Mac which can display the music label?

Tags: macos, mp3, tags, id3, mp3-player

Is there a music (mp3) player on Mac which is able to display the ID3-TPUB (Music Label) tag in list view? For me the label is as important as the artist, so I would like to view them side by side without having to go to an ID3 edit-window or something similar.

I am not looking for other ways to store this information, I am looking for a program which can display this (standard) tag.
[image: List view image]

**Edit1:**
FLAC-support is a plus.

Comment: I believe ID3-TPUB was part of the ID3 2.3 draft, and iTunes supported up to ID3 2.4 last I checked. Are you sure the songs have the Publisher (TPUB) metadata intact? Any chance it was converted by iTunes and damaged/lost?

Comment: I just checked (recent version of iTunes) – there is no Label / Publisher field available.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe I’m sure my metadata is intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is a regular tag, [**Quod Libet**](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/) should be able to display it.

See their FAQ: [How do I add custom / unusual tags to the columns in the song list?](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/faq.html#how-do-i-add-custom-unusual-tags-to-the-columns-in-the-song-list)

> 2. Right-click the song list header bar and select *Customize Headers* from the context menu (or click *Preferences* from the main menu and select Song List)
> 3. In the *Others* field, click *Edit*, then *Add*, and enter the custom tag name, remembering that they are case-sensitive.

Quod Libet is [available](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/downloads.html) cross-platform (GNU/Linux, Windows, Mac OS X), free/libre open source software, and gratis. I don’t know how it runs under OS X, but [I can recommend it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4081/60) at least for GNU/Linux, especially for huge music collections.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much @unor! For others: you can add the record label by right clicking on the menu line (where title, album, etc. is), then press `Production Headers` –> `Organization`. I will wait a few days if there are more interesting entries until marking your answer as the accepted one.